# Tensorflow Object Detection and Image Cropping for Data Extraction

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, data-extraction

Below is my code that detect the regions (tables, paragraphs) from invoice and and crop the detected region from the invoice. I am facing issues while performing data extraction on cropped images as images are very small. I am passing cropped image to tesseract for text extraction code below.

Is there any other options where we can perform extraction over the entire image but only for detected region instead of cropping the image. Cropping leads to loss of image quality and also tesseract text extraction is poor quality.

```
for idx in range(len(bboxes)):
if bscores[idx] >= Threshold:
  #Region of Interest
  y_min = int(bboxes[idx][0] * im_height)
  x_min = int(bboxes[idx][1] * im_width)
  y_max = int(bboxes[idx][2] * im_height)
  x_max = int(bboxes[idx][3] * im_width)

  class_label = category_index[int(bclasses[idx])]['name']
  class_labels.append(class_label)
  bbox.append([x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max, class_label, float(bscores[idx])])

  #Crop Image - Working Code
  cropped_image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image, y_min, x_min, y_max - y_min, x_max - x_min).numpy().astype(np.int32)

  # encode_jpeg encodes a tensor of type uint8 to string
  output_image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(cropped_image)
  # decode_jpeg decodes the string tensor to a tensor of type uint8
  #output_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(output_image)

  score = bscores[idx] * 100

  file_name = tf.constant(OUTPUT_PATH+image_name[:-4]+'_'+str(idx)+'_'+class_label+'_'+str(round(score))+'%'+'_'+os.path.splitext(image_name)[1])

  writefile = tf.io.write_file(file_name, output_image)
```

Code for text extraction

```
        import cv2
    import pytesseract

    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"     

    # Grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
    image = cv2.imread('1.png')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # Morph open to remove noise and invert image
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
    invert = 255 - opening

    # Perform text extraction
    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(invert, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
    print(data)

    cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
    cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
    cv2.imshow('invert', invert)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: So the issue is, that the resolution of the cropped image is too low to work well with tesseract? When cropping the image, the image doesn't get resized (only the rest of the image is cut off), so feeding the original (aka not cropped) image into tesseract would result in the same resolution (for the text) because there is no downsampling or resolution reduction when cropping images. Am I correct in the assumption?

Comment: Yes, cropped images are too small for extraction

Comment: But again: cropping images won't lower the resolution of the text (the amount per pixel for the region of interest doesn't change while cropping). When tesseract throws an error due to minimum resolution you could try to upsample the cropped image first, before feeding it to tesseract.

Comment: I think you'll have more chances of getting answers if people can reproduce your problem. eg: give similar images with the same problem, or at the very least, the resolution of said images, so people can make a solution that works for this problem.